# Doctrine ODM (MongoDB) - Get a complete array of an object?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-orm

iv'e got a problem to receive a **complete array** (with **all the data of the embedded childs collections** and objects) of my document. My document looks exactly like this one:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Document(collection="user") */
class User {

/** @Id */
protected $id;

/** @String */
protected $firstname;

/** @String */
protected $lastname;

/** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Email") */
protected $email;

/** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Address") */
protected $address;

/** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Subscription") */
protected $subscription;


/**
* Construct the user
*
* @param   array $properties
* @throws  User_Exception
*/
public function __construct(array $properties = array()) {

    $this->email = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->subscription = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach($properties as $name => $value){
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }

}


...
```

---

**I need a complete array of an embedded collection to output the whole data and render it by json**. My query looks like this:

```
$query = $this->_dbContainer->getDocumentManager()->createQueryBuilder('User')->field('deletedAt')->exists(false);                          
$result = $query->field('id')->equals($id)->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

---

For example, if i call the `toArray()` function like this:

```
$array = $result->getSubscription()->toArray();
print_r($array);
```

---

Then the output ist just an array on top level:

```
[0] => Object Subscription...
[1] => Object Subscription...
...
```

---

How can i easily get an array like this?

```
[0] => array('subscriptionLabel' => 'value1', 'field' => 'value1', ...)
[1] => array('subscriptionLabel' => 'value2', 'field' => 'value2', ...)
...
```

---

Are there any best practises or maybe some missing helper scripts to prevent something ugly like this code (how to handle child -> child -> child szenarios? ugly -> ugly ugly -> ugly ugly ugly -> ...):

```
$example = array();
foreach($result->getSubscription() as $key => $subscription) {
    $example[$key]['subscriptionLabel'] = $subscription->getSubscriptionLabel();
    $example[$key]['field'] = $subscription->getField();
    ...
}
```

Thanks a lot,
Stephan

Answer (score 13):

Damn simple answer! Just use ->hydrate(false) and it's done.

> For find queries the results by
>   default are hydrated and you get
>   document objects back instead of
>   arrays. You can disable this and get
>   the raw results directly back from
>   mongo by using the hydrate(false)
>   method:

```
<?php

$users = $dm->createQueryBuilder('User')
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();

print_r($users);
```

Comment: Yes, but what if you have [schema migration logic](http://jwage.com/2010/07/30/doctrine-mongodb-odm-schema-migrations/) within your model? All this would get skipped if you bypass the hydrate.

Comment: if you have schema migration logic, you could implement a toArray()-Function for your Documents where you load all the get() methods of the Document and return it as an array

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same need recently and solved it by creating a base class for all my entities with a toArray() function and JsonSerializable. It converts all nested references as well.

```
/**
 * @ODM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseDocument implements \JsonSerializable 
{
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return $this->toArray();
    }

    public function toArray() {
        $getter_names = get_class_methods(get_class($this));
        $gettable_attributes = array();
        foreach ($getter_names as $key => $funcName) {
            if(substr($funcName, 0, 3) === 'get') {
                $propName = strtolower(substr($funcName, 3, 1));
                $propName .= substr($funcName, 4);
                $value = $this->$funcName();
                if (is_object($value) && get_class($value) == 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection') {
                    $values = array();
                    $collection = $value;
                    foreach ($collection as $obj) {
                        $values[] = $obj->toArray();
                    }
                    $gettable_attributes[$propName] = $values;
                }
                else {
                    $gettable_attributes[$propName] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $gettable_attributes;
    }
}
```

Now I can serialize the entity as an array or json string with json_encode($doc). Bam.

Answer (score 1):

Tanks to Rooster242, you can even recursively apply toArray to embedded documents which themself extends BaseDocument by using the php **is_subclass_of** function :

```
/**
 * @ODM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseDocument implements \JsonSerializable 
{
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return $this->toArray();
    }

    public function toArray() {
        $getter_names = get_class_methods(get_class($this));
        $gettable_attributes = array();
        foreach ($getter_names as $key => $funcName) {
            if(substr($funcName, 0, 3) === 'get') {
                $propName = strtolower(substr($funcName, 3, 1));
                $propName .= substr($funcName, 4);
                $value = $this->$funcName();
                if (is_object($value) && is_subclass_of($value,"BaseDocument")) {
                    $gettable_attributes[$propName] = $value->toArray();
                } elseif (is_object($value) && get_class($value) == 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection') {
                    $values = array();
                    $collection = $value;
                    foreach ($collection as $obj) {
                        if (is_subclass_of($obj,"BaseDocument")) {
                            $values[] = $obj->toArray();
                        } else {
                            $values[] = $obj;
                        }
                    }
                    $gettable_attributes[$propName] = $values;
                }
                else {
                    $gettable_attributes[$propName] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $gettable_attributes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made this a bit more generic, works perfect. Just dont forget to extend it with your documents and embeds.

```
<?php
namespace App\Documents;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\PersistentCollection;

/**
 * @ODM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseDocument implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return $this->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $getterNames = get_class_methods(get_class($this));
        $gettableAttributes = [];
        foreach ($getterNames as $funcName) {
            if (substr($funcName, 0, 3) !== 'get') {
                continue;
            }

            $propName = strtolower(substr($funcName, 3, 1));
            $propName .= substr($funcName, 4);
            $value = $this->$funcName();

            $gettableAttributes[$propName] = $value;


            if (is_object($value)) {
                if ($value instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                    $values = [];
                    $collection = $value;
                    foreach ($collection as $obj) {
                        /** @var BaseDocument $obj */
                        if ($obj instanceof \JsonSerializable) {
                            $values[] = $obj->toArray();
                        } else {
                            $values[] = $obj;
                        }
                    }
                    $gettableAttributes[$propName] = $values;
                } elseif ($value instanceof \JsonSerializable) {
                    /** @var BaseDocument $value */
                    $gettableAttributes[$propName] = $value->toArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return $gettableAttributes;
    }
}
```